# AVQueuePlayer video is not working in Swift

Tags: swift, avplayer, avqueueplayer

I am currently trying to implement advertisement with video in Swift. I tried to use `AVPlayerViewController` and `AVQueuePlayer`. However `AVQueuePlayer` is not playing the videos after first one finishes. Here is my code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var adItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: adUrl!))
    var videoItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: videoUrl))

    player = AVQueuePlayer(items: NSArray(objects: adItem,videoItem) as [AnyObject])
    playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    playerController.player = player
    self.addChildViewController(playerController)
    self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
    playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
}
```

Can you tell me what is my wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Have you managed to find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you guys tried this?

```
let quePlayer = AVQueuePlayer.init(items: allVideos)
quePlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.Advance
```

Answer (score -3):

I have try this and it works with me

```
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString as String)
    self.player = AVPlayer(URL: url!)
```